# Save value just during activity life

Tags: android

I have a main Activity, and a Dialog that pops when I click a button from the main Activity. In this dialog, I can select a value, and this value is returned back to the main Activity.

When I first start the Dialog, the value showed is "1". If I the select f.e. "5", I need this value to be saved the way that next time I open the Dialog, this will be the value shown.

But, every time I close the app, I need this to reset, I mean, If I close and the open again the app, I'll need the number shown to be the "1" again.
've worked with sharedPreferences, but this keeps saving the value even if I close the app.

Comment: Create one Constant class and saved values there.

Comment: @M D I don't know if this is the correct approach. I just need a way to save an object's state every time I close the Dialog, and retrieve this state every time I open the Dialog again

Comment: this way is better becoz it you used preference then it'll store your value as permanent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SharedPreferences, and save the default value 1 **as you exit your app.** Then load it when you start the application. During the lifetime of app, you can still use SharedPreferences for saving values between Dialog and main Activity, just save the default value that you want to have when starting the app anew - do it as you exit.

Comment: Ok, just one thing. If the value I would like to save is an Imagebutton, how do I do it? I mean, if in the dialog I've got 10 ImageButtons, each one with a number from 1 to 10, and what I need is to save the value of an object `ImageButton imgbutton;` which will contain the view of the selected button

Comment: As this is an entirely new issue, I'd post another question on SO.